# Is there a way to ungroup or change the order of same app buttons in Windows 10 taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Windows 10 groups together the buttons for the same app in the taskbar. Is there a way to ungroup them or at least change the order of the buttons in the taskbar?
I know that 7+ Taskbar Tweaker can do it but my company doesn't allow this tool to be installed.
If there's no way to do this in Windows like in the registry for example, perhaps there's another similar tool?

Comment: Do you mean taskbar icons for the individual programs running on your computer?

Comment: Yes. They are called buttons.

Comment: The 7+ Taskbar Tweaker runs as a background task and uses hooks and process injection to work.  It doesn't use the windows registry and I don't know of any other way.  You can find the source for the Taskbar Tweaker [here](https://github.com/m417z/7-Taskbar-Tweaker).. you won't believe how involved the code is.  He wouldn't have written all of that code if he didn't need to.

Comment: Señor CMasMas I mentioned I can't use it. My company's security measures flagged it as a potentially unsafe app. Must be because of the hooks and oddball stuff that Tweaker uses.